# Filter tree-like collapsible content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview with multiple collapsible content (tree-like). The filter automatically expand the last block from collapsible-sets, and not the true block/div (value from that collapsible div) searched.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tzontonel/vj74fycy/)

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$("#mineralslist").on("filterablefilter", function (event, ui) {
    if ($("#mineralslist .ui-screen-hidden").length == 0) {
        $('#mineralslist [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible("collapse");
    } else {
        $('#mineralslist [data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible("expand");

    }

});
</script>

<div data-role="content" id="iama">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="mineralslist" data-inset='true' data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search mineral...">
        <li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset='false'>
                 <h3>Native elements</h3>

                <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                         <h3>Gold group</h3>

                        <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Gold</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Au</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>Rich yellow</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Silver</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Ag</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>Silver-white</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Copper</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Cu</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>Brown, copper red, light pink, red</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Lead</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Pb</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>Grey, but often coated</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Aluminum</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Al</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>Grayish-White</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                         <h3>Platinum group</h3>

                        <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Platinum</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Pt</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>Steel grey to dark grey</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Iridium</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>(Ir,Os,Ru)</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>White</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Palladium</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>(Pd,Pt)</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>White</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                         <h3>Carbon Polymorph group</h3>

                        <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Diamond</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>C</td>
                                            <td>Isometric</td>
                                            <td>Colourless</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div data-role="collapsible">
                                 <h4>Graphite</h4>

                                <table data-role="table" id="mineral-table" class="ui-shadow table-stroke">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="label">Formula</th>
                                            <th class="label">System</th>
                                            <th class="label">Colour</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>C</td>
                                            <td>Hexagonal</td>
                                            <td>Iron black to steel-grey</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset='false'>
                 <h3>Organic compounds</h3>

                <p>Answer.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Example: I want to search for *Iridium* and I obtain these:
[image]

What I'm trying to obtain is to expand only the block filtered. Like in this image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try jQ :contains() selector`s prefix

```
var s = $('input').val() // itidium
var list = $('#mineralslist').find('h4:contains("'+s+'")').css({'display':'block','opacity':1})
```

And after you must show all parent elements of list

Comment: ok - I create this example - its pretty simple code
http://codepen.io/alexDesign/pen/BNoXRa
You can see how I use recursion to show all parents before I dont came back to main parent <div>

Comment: I'm looking forward for your idea, but I'm trying to imagine how can I adapt your idea to collapsible data-role.

Comment: Yeah your markup is more hard) If I understand right - you must add to each parent div class "ui-collapsible-collapsed" - it will display current <div> element.